# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Iscontains' of undefined" in this video script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax, video.js

I am using AJAX to call my backend code, I get the URLs from the database and render to DOM. It displays videos accordingly. But I am getting

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Iscontains' of undefined`

and the video fails to play.

```
function LoadLatestVideos(s) {
     jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         async: true,
         url: "videoplayer.aspx/LoadLatestVideos",
         data: "{InvitaionID:" + s + "}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         mimeType: "video/mp4",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
             for (var i = 0; i <= response.d.length; i++) {
                 // $('#Latest').append('<div id="divId' + i + ' " style="height:80px;width:80px;background-image:url(\'/WeddingAlbum/1000/' + response.d[i].Imagename + '.jpg\'); "> </div>');
                 var obj, source;
                 var s = 'youtube'
                 obj = document.createElement('video');
                 $(obj).attr('preload', 'auto');
                 alert(response.d[i].Iscontains);
                 if (response.d[i].Iscontains == 'true')
                     $(obj).attr('data-setup', '{"width":"100%", "techOrder":["'+s+'"], "src":"' + response.d[i].OnlineVideourl+'"}');
                 else
                     $(obj).attr('data-setup', '{"width":"100%"}');
                 // $(obj).attr('controls', '');
                 $(obj).attr('poster', 'assets/_con/images/video-poster.jpg');
                 $(obj).attr('class', 'video-js vjs-default-skin responsive-embed-16x9');
                 $(".m12").append(obj);
                 if (response.d[i].Iscontains = 'false') {
                     source = document.createElement('source');
                     $(source).attr('type', 'video/mp4');
                     $(source).attr('src', 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4');
                     $(obj).append(source);
                 }
             }
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         },
         error: function (response) {

         }
     });
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if (response.d[i].Iscontains = 'false')` needs to be `if (response.d[i].Iscontains == 'false')`.

Comment: Have you tried logging `response`?

Comment: `response.d` can be null or an empty array. Though if the array is empty and the length equals 0, it will loop for once (`i` = 0 and the length = 0, enter loop).

Answer (score 0):

`i <= response.d.length` should be `i < response.d.length`, because the length of an array is always the highest index plus 1. The loop will go through an undefined array index after the last defined one.

---

Two more (potential) mistakes for you to review:

- `if (response.d[i].Iscontains = 'false')` doesn’t have a comparison. Replace `=` by `==`
- The *strings* `"true"` and `"false"` should probably be replaced by the *booleans* `true` and `false`, or rather, if they should be replaced, just use `response.d[i].Iscontains` instead of `response.d[i].Iscontains == 'true'` and `!response.d[i].Iscontains` instead of `response.d[i].Iscontains == 'false'`

Comment: It worked for me. But the video is not playing in the chrome and firefox

Comment: @user1844634 Did you replace the `if` statement as per the first comment?

Comment: @user1844634 Also, did you really mean the _strings_ `"true"` and `"false"` or the _booleans_ `true` and `false`?

Comment: Editing my actual code above please have a look. url there is a youtube url which i am getting from database. it's failing to load the video

Comment: @user1844634 What does the video element look like if you inspect it?

Comment: <video preload="auto" src="" data-setup="{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;100%&quot;, &quot;techOrder&quot;:[&quot;youtube&quot;], &quot;src&quot;:&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02iCeHFsGyc&quot;}" controls="controls" poster="assets/_con/images/video-poster.jpg" class="video-js vjs-default-skin responsive-embed-16x9"></video> this is how it looked.

Comment: Shouldn’t the src property have an `http://` at the beginning? Also, I don’t see any code where you actually place the `src` attribute of the `video`.

Comment: data-setup contains the src attribute that will contain the location of the video. Just observed that if place that code of the dynmaic video creation in jquery onload it worked for me. with in the ajax tags it's giving the issue. any thoughts what's wrong in the ajax tags

Comment: Okay, this is where you should research for yourself and ask a new question if you couldn’t find a solution. I’m editing your question to include your previous code because it’s invalidating the problem of the question.